# ngTable Grouping does not work after integrating in the project. replicating the data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to use ngTable grouping technique in my project I took the sample from here

[Demo ngTable grouping](http://ng-table.com/#/grouping/demo-grouping-basic)

I've minimized the code and its working perfectly here is the codepen

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVZPow

```
<html>   <div ng-app="myApp" class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <h2 class="page-header">Grouping - basic example</h2>

</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6" ng-controller="demoController as demo">
  <h3>ngTable directive</h3>
  <table ng-table="demo.tableParams" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-hover">
    <colgroup>
      <col width="60%" />
      <col width="20%" />
      <col width="20%" />
    </colgroup>
    <tr class="ng-table-group" ng-repeat-start="group in $groups">
      <td colspan="3">
        <a href="" ng-click="group.$hideRows = !group.$hideRows">
          <span class="glyphicon" ng-class="{ 'glyphicon-chevron-right': group.$hideRows, 'glyphicon-chevron-down': !group.$hideRows }"></span>
          <strong>{{ group.value }}</strong>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-hide="group.$hideRows" ng-repeat="user in group.data" ng-repeat-end>
      <td sortable="'country'" data-title="'Country'" groupable="'country'" ng-if="false">
        {{user.country}}
      </td>
      <td sortable="'name'" data-title="'Name'" groupable="'name'">
        {{user.name}}
      </td>
      <td sortable="'age'" data-title="'Age'" groupable="'age'">
        {{user.age}}
      </td>
      <td sortable="'money'" data-title="'Money'">
        {{user.money}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
 </div>

</div>
</div></html>
```

But when I tried to integrate it in my project its giving strange error.

Whenever I try to sort,change the pagination or toggle the grouping its replicating the data and appending it at the end of table. This is happening for every click.

I tried by changing the angularjs versions but its not working.

What might be the possibilities of this problem?

Comment: If you don't share some other info (the "strange" error, some portion of your project in which has to be merged the code above, etc...) we can't understand what's the problem

Comment: I'm not sure what other info do I need to add as My project is very large. I had tried many other things but nothing seems to work. any how thanks ;)